# How can I give the tiles in my tilemap a sprite?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am quite new to Python and this is quite a newbie question, but how can I assigne the tiles in my tilemap sprites? Currently, I am just drawing rectangles in the tilemap where they are supposed to be, and it works fine. However, I want to add my own textures.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

tilesize = 64
mapwidth, mapheight = 20, 13
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((mapwidth*tilesize, mapheight*tilesize))

WALLTOP, WALLBOT, GRASS = range(3)
wallTop = (0, 102, 0)
wallBot = (51, 51, 0,)
grass =   (0, 65, 0)

colors = {
    WALLTOP : wallTop,
    WALLBOT : wallBot,
    GRASS   : grass
}

# Tilemap
tilemap = [
    [WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLBOT, WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,     WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,     WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, GRASS, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,     WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLBOT, GRASS, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,     WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   WALLBOT, WALLBOT, GRASS,   GRASS, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,     WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,     WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,     WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,     WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,     WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS, GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,   GRASS,     WALLTOP],
    [WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP, WALLTOP],

# Main loop
running = True
while running:
    # Loop through the rows of the tilemap
    for row in range(mapheight):
        # Loop through the columns of the tilemap
        for column in range(mapwidth):
            # Draw the picture at the position in the tilemap
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colors[tilemap[row][column]], (column*tilesize, row*tilesize, tilesize, tilesize))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace drawing rect with blitting images corresponding to each element of the map.

Replace the `colors` dict and the color definitions with a dictionary like this:

```
tileimages = {
    WALLTOP : pygame.image.load("path/to/image_walltop.png").convert(),
    WALLBOT : pygame.image.load("path/to/image_wallbot.png").convert(),
    GRASS   : pygame.image.load("path/to/image_grass.png").convert(),
}
```

[pygame.image.load](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) will load an image, which of course needs to be prepared in advance with an image editor or whatever and stored somewhere on your system. Be sure to provide the correct path.
Here I used `png`, but could be other formats, for more info on supported formats read the documentation I linked.

To blit the image, in your mainloop replace the `draw.rect` line with:

```
screen.blit(tileimages[tilemap[row][column]], (column*tilesize, row*tilesize))
```

**Careful:** here is assumed that the images have the correct size, so it is a `tilesize x tilesize` image (which becomes a `tilesize x tilesize` Surface in pygame). If this is not the case, the result will be bad. You need to use [pygame.transform.scale](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) to rescale it to a `tilesize x tilesize` Surface.

So your `tileimages` dict should look like:

```
tileimages = {
    WALLTOP : pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("path/to/image_walltop.png").convert(), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    WALLBOT : pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("path/to/image_wallbot.png").convert(), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    GRASS   : pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("path/to/image_grass.png").convert(), (tilesize, tilesize)),
}
```

Comment: Wow, this worked! Thank you so much. I forgot about the blit part, so i was hardstuck for a while. Cheers!